# Can't deploy my app to weblogic 10.3 due to "Unmarshaller failed"

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

I had my application developed by Jdeloper 11g working well, but upon trying to deploy it on weblogic 10.3 on another machine with new installed Jdeveloper I got the next error, can anyone help ?:

<May 2, 2023 5:44:23 PM GMT>    <Unable to load descriptor C:\Users\ASD\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\o.j2ee\drs\Most/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml of module Most. The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:161)
at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
at weblogic.application.ApplicationDescriptor.getWeblogicApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.java:324)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:181)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationForAppDeployment(MBeanConverter.java:67)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.setupNew81MBean(MBeanConverter.java:315)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.compatibilityProcessor(ActivateOperation.java:81)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.setupPrepare(AbstractOperation.java:295)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:97)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.LibraryRefBeanImpl@872e9236(/LibraryRefs[[CompoundKey: adf.oracle.domain]])"
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:54)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType$BeanRuntimeProperty.setValue(RuntimeBindingType.java:539)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType$QNameRuntimeProperty.fillCollection(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:381)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MultiIntermediary.getFinalValue(MultiIntermediary.java:52)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType.getFinalObjectFromIntermediary(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:140)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:200)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:169)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65)
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:150)
... 27 more
Caused by: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.LibraryRefBeanImpl@872e9236(/LibraryRefs[[CompoundKey: adf.oracle.domain]])"
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.ReferenceManager.registerBean(ReferenceManager.java:231)
at weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.setLibraryRefs(WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.java:1440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:48)
... 35 more
.>
<May 2, 2023 5:44:23 PM GMT>    <Failed to create App/Comp mbeans for AppDeploymentMBean Most. Error - weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed.
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:193)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.LibraryRefBeanImpl@872e9236(/LibraryRefs[[CompoundKey: adf.oracle.domain]])"
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.ReferenceManager.registerBean(ReferenceManager.java:231)
at weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.setLibraryRefs(WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.java:1440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

<May 2, 2023 5:44:23 PM GMT>    <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1683049462899' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed'
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:193)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.LibraryRefBeanImpl@872e9236(/LibraryRefs[[CompoundKey: adf.oracle.domain]])"
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.ReferenceManager.registerBean(ReferenceManager.java:231)
at weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.setLibraryRefs(WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.java:1440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

<May 2, 2023 5:44:23 PM GMT>    <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'Most'.>
<May 2, 2023 5:44:23 PM GMT>    <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:193)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.LibraryRefBeanImpl@872e9236(/LibraryRefs[[CompoundKey: adf.oracle.domain]])"
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.ReferenceManager.registerBean(ReferenceManager.java:231)
at weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.setLibraryRefs(WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.java:1440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

[08:44:23 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[08:44:23 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[08:44:23 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)

##### Cannot run application Most due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.

[Application Most stopped and undeployed from Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]

I tried deploying another app which works well on my old machine, but it give the same result